# Terminal emulators start without user groups

Tags: command-line, terminator

I have used terminator as my default terminal for years. Recently I found docker commands started requiring `sudo` to run, and while debugging this, discovered terminal emulators on my system (terminator, MATE Terminal, Xfce Terminal, XTerm) start without loading many of my user's groups.

In these emulators, running `groups` yields:

```
mark@mypc:~$ groups
mark
```

When I run `groups` in Gnome Terminal, however:

```
mark@mypc:~$ groups
mark adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

I have tried apt remove & purge terminator, and reinstalled, with the same result. From Gnome Terminal, I can run docker commands without sudo (which was my goal initially). However I would prefer to continue to use terminator as my default emulator. So, How can I have the terminal emulator start with all of my users groups enabled?

I have tried apt remove & purge terminator, and reinstalled, with the same result. However, when I user Gnome Terminal to launch Terminator, terminator starts with all of my user groups.

I'm using Ubunutu 18.04 with cinnamon desktop environment. Thanks in advance!

Output of pstree in broken terminator instance:

```
mark@mypc:~$ pstree -sp $$
systemd(1)───terminator(26282)───bash(26291)───pstree(26578)
```

Output of pstree in (working) Gnome Terminal:

```
mark@mypc:~$ pstree -sp $$
systemd(1)───systemd(3363)───gnome-terminal-(30711)───bash(22983)───pstree(24955)
```

Comment: @Ravexina Seems like an honest mistake. OP was adding details while I was editing the formatting. (and I just added back the changes that were lost.)

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah I figure it out ...

Comment: Sorry @wjandrea!

Comment: @MarkS Open a terminal with issue like: "terminator", run: `pstree -sp $$` also run it in "gnome-terminal" add the output to your question, it might be helpful to us spotting the problem.

Comment: @MarkS No problem at all. It's your question :)

Comment: @MarkS Thanks see my edited comment and please edit the output again

Comment: I wonder if it's related to this: [User not being initialized correctly on login](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418)

Comment: @MarkS I want the output with `pstree -sp $$` instead of `pstree -s $$` to know the process IDs and would you explain how you run the terminals, I'm not familiar with mate.

Comment: @steeldriver +1 I guess you spot the issue

Comment: @MarkS check this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454593/groups-not-registering-in-x Also +1 to the question it's really interesting for me.

Comment: Thank you all - I am reviewing the links from steeldriver and Ravexina. upon first glance I don't find errors in auth.log but these do seem very similar. I also fixed the pstree output.

Comment: Thanks everyone - the solution in the link from Ravexina ( which is in the link from steeldriver) fixed it. WRT stackexchange ettiquette, should I answer this question myself, or ??

Comment: @MarkS Sure, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution proposed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454715/292253, and the issue is resolved. In summary:

> I just commented out the following lines in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`
>
> ```
> auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
> auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
> ```

and restart

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I think I ran into this because I had started with kubuntu, then switched to ubuntu since gnome-shell works better in my vm. Thanks for sharing your solution.